# Getting SESSION_ID from skrill server

Tags: php, session, curl, payment-gateway

Please help me i am having some trouble.
What i want to do is integrate moneybooker in my website.
I studied the "Merchant Integration Manual version 6.17" in 2.3.2 Topic where i have to create and get a SESSION_ID form skrill server by sending payment parameters by post and get the SESSION_ID this session will hold my transaction information like amount and my account.

By using below code i can't retrieve the SESSION_ID from their server.

```
$url = "https:www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl";

$post_data = array (  
        "prepare_only" => 1,  
        "amount" => 10,
        "currency" => 'USD',
        "detail1_description" => "Description",
        "detail1_text" => "Text",
        "pay_to_email" => "****my**accoutn@yahoo.com" 
    );  


$head = get_web_page($url, $post_data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($head);
echo "</pre>";



function get_web_page( $url, $post_data )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     //we are doing a POST request  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
     //adding the post variables to the request  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

The above code works for other sites but not for moneybooker.
But when i submit simple html form, session id is created and shown but i am not being redirected to my site !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding cookies support

```
$fh = fopen("cookies.txt", "a+") or die("Can't open file!");
fclose($fh);

$ch = curl_init();



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with an array, the request will be sent as multipart/form-data, try changing that line to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
```